# How to cancel async Observable thread on unsubscription

Tags: java, android, rx-java

How can I cancel async Observable thread on unsubscribe ?
I have following situation:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> api.UploadData(data))
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(subscriber);
```

After unsubscribe on Activity destroy data is still uploading on other thread, I want to cancel upload operation. How can I do that ?

Comment: How would you cancel `api.UploadData(data)`?

Comment: Unsubscription sends an interrupt to the thread that runs your `fromCallable`. Maybe the `uploadData` doesn't respond to Thread interrupts?

Comment: @akarnokd hmm `uploadData` method has standard okhttp sync. post request and nothing more, maybe it is a problem with `ThreadPoolExecutor` ?

Comment: If you are using the Java built-in executors then it should work. You can verify it by having a Thread.sleep in the callable and see if it throws an InterruptedException.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `doOnUnsubscribe` and achieve your requirement.

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> api.UploadData(data))
   .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
   .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .doOnUnsubscribe(() -> api.StopUpload())
   .subscribe(subscriber);
```